Convergence of a Sequence in the GNS Space of a von Neumann Algebra with Semi-finite Trace under the $\sigma$-Weak Topology
Let $ M $ be a von Neumann algebra. A Semi-finite trace on $ M^+ $ is a function $\phi$ on $ M^+ $, taking non-negative, possibly infinite, real values, possessing the following properties:

Linearity: $\phi(a + b) = \phi(a) + \phi(b) $ for all $ a, b \in M^+ $.
Positivity: $ \phi(\lambda a) = \lambda \phi(a) $ for all $ a \in M^+ $ and $ \lambda > 0 $ (with the convention that $ 0 \cdot \infty = 0 $.
Self-adjointness: $ \phi(x^* x) = \phi(xx^*) $ for all $ x \in M $.
Semi-finiteness: For any $ 0\ne a \in M^+ $, there exists $ 0\ne  b \in M^+ $ and  $ b \le a $ such that $ \phi(b) < +\infty $.

Let us now consider a faithful semi-finite normal trace $\phi$ on $M^+$ and the set $~\mathcal N:=\{x\in M: \phi(x^*x)<\infty\}.$ Define an inner product on $\mathcal N$ by $$\langle x,y\rangle:=\phi(y^*x),~\forall x,y\in \mathcal N.$$ Now denote the completion of $\left(\mathcal N,\langle \rangle \right)^-$ by $\mathcal H_\phi$. And consider $x \to x_\phi~(\forall x\in \mathcal N)$ is the embedding of $\mathcal N$ in $\mathcal H_\phi$. Let $\left\{x_\phi^{(n)}\right\}_{n\ge 1}$  be a sequence in $\mathcal H_\phi$ corresponds to the sequence $\{x^{(n)}\}_{n\ge 1}$ in $\mathcal N$ such that $x_\phi^{(n)} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. I want to show that $x^{(n)} \to 0$ in $\sigma-$weak topology when $n \to \infty$.
First note that $x_\phi^{(n)} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ yields that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left\|x_\phi^{(n)}\right\|_{\mathcal H_\phi}^2=0.$$ Now observe that,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left\|x_\phi^{(n)}\right\|_{\mathcal H_\phi}^2=0 \implies \lim_{n\to \infty} \phi\left(\left(x^{(n)}\right)^*x^{(n)}\right)=0.$$ Let us now assume $x^{(n)} \to x$ in $\sigma-$weak topology when $n \to \infty$. Since $\phi$ is normal and involution is continuous under $\sigma-$weak topology we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \phi\left(x^{(n)}\right)=x~\text{ and }~ \lim_{n\to \infty} \phi\left(\left(x^{(n)}\right)^*\right)=x^*.$$
I'm trying to prove that $x=0$, but I'm stuck. Could you please help me out? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is not true. In fact, you can even choose $\phi$ to be finite. For example, let $M = L^\infty[0, 1]$ and $\phi$ be the integration w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Let $x^{(n)} = \frac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{n}1_{(2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]}$. Then $\|x_\phi^{(n)}\|^2 = \frac{1}{n^2} \to 0$, so $x_\phi^{(n)} \to 0$. But $x^{(n)} \not\to 0$ $\sigma$-weakly. Indeed, $f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n2^{\frac{n}{2}}1_{(2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]} \in L^1[0, 1] = L^\infty[0, 1]_\ast$ as $\|f\|_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n2^{-\frac{n}{2}} < \infty$. But $\int fx^{(n)} \, dm = 1 \not\to 0$.

Some further observations/insights:
To say $x^{(n)} \to 0$ $\sigma$-weakly is to say $\langle f, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi \to 0$ for every $f \in L^1(M, \phi) = M_\ast$, whereas $x_\phi^{(n)} \to 0$ means $\|x^{(n)}\|_{L^2(M, \phi)} \to 0$. Now, if $f$ is actually contained in $L^2(M, \phi)$, this is fine - it just follows from Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$|\langle f, x^{(n)} \rangle|_\phi \leq \|f\|_{L^2(M, \phi)}\|x^{(n)}\|_{L^2(M, \phi)} \to 0$$
But it is not the case that $L^1(M, \phi) \subset L^2(M, \phi)$, so $x^{(n)} \to 0$ $\sigma$-weakly needs not hold in general, as we have already seen. However, we observe that,

This is true if $\phi$ is supported on an atomic part of $M$ and there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\phi(p) \geq C$ for every minimal projection $p$ within the support of $\phi$. In that case you actually do have $L^1(M, \phi) \subset L^2(M, \phi)$ - the proof is similar to the sequence space case, i.e., $l^1 \subset l^2$;
This is also true if you already know $x^{(n)} \to x$ $\sigma$-weakly for some $x \in M$. Indeed, we have already seen that $\langle f, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi \to 0$ for all $f \in L^2(M, \phi)$. But as $x^{(n)} \to x$ $\sigma$-weakly, we must have $\langle f, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi \to \langle f, x \rangle_\phi$ as well for $f \in L^1(M, \phi)$. Thus, $\langle f, x \rangle = 0$ whenever $f \in L^1(M, \phi) \cap L^2(M, \phi)$. The latter space is dense in $L^1(M, \phi)$, so we have $x = 0$;
This is also true if there exists $C > 0$ s.t. $\|x^{(n)}\|_\infty \leq C$ (where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denotes the operator norm) for all $n$. Indeed, then for any $f \in L^1(M, \phi)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, we may choose $f’ \in L^1(M, \phi) \cap L^2(M, \phi)$ with $\|f - f’\|_{L^1(M, \phi)} < \frac{\epsilon}{2C}$. But then $\langle f’, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi \to 0$, so for large enough $n$, we have $|\langle f’, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. But then, for large enough $n$,

$$\begin{split}
|\langle f, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi| &\leq |\langle f’, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi| + |\langle f - f’, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi|\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \|f - f’\|_{L^1(M, \phi)}\|x^{(n)}\|_\infty\\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&= \epsilon
\end{split}$$
So $\langle f, x^{(n)} \rangle_\phi \to 0$ for all $f \in L^1(M, \phi)$, i.e., $x^{(n)} \to 0$ $\sigma$-weakly. (A final comment here: Case 2 is actually a special case of Case 3 - any $\sigma$-weakly convergent sequence is automatically uniformly bounded in operator norm, which follows from the uniform boundedness principle.)

Is the map $x\mapsto x_\phi$ for $x\in \mathcal N$ injective from $\mathcal N$ to $L^2(M,\phi)$? I know for finite trace it happens, but I am not sure about semi-finite trace $\phi$.

@DenOfZero It is iff $\phi$ is faithful. Just write down the definitions. This is obvious.

In addition to David's answer, note that every weak$^\ast$ convergent sequence is bounded by the uniform boundedness theorem (not true for nets, though). Hence boundedness is a necessary additional condition for $(x^{(n)})$ to converge in the weak$^\ast$ topology.
Conversely, if $(x^{(n)})$ is bounded and $x_\phi^{(n)}\to 0$ in $H_\phi$, then
$$
\lVert \pi_\phi(x^{(n)})y_\phi\rVert_2^2=\phi(y^\ast (x^{(n)})^\ast x^{(n)}y)=\phi(x^{(n)}yy^\ast (x^{(n)})^\ast)\leq \lVert y\rVert^2\phi((x^{(n)})^\ast x^{(n)})\to 0
$$
for every $y\in \mathcal N$. Since $(\pi_\phi(x^{(n)}))$ is bounded and $\{y_\phi\mid y\in \mathcal N\}$ is dense in $H_\phi$, it follows that $x^{(n)}\to 0$ in the strong operator topology (note that the strong operator topology on bounded subsets of $M$ does not depend on the representation). In particular, $x^{(n)}\to 0$ in the weak$^\ast$ topology.
